How do I find the message ID of a mail from the attachment ID, using gmail APIs
working with get message attachment method, which has both message id and attachment id as parameters, I found that the attachment id is unique, and the message id parameter is not required to get data.
So by that logic can I get the message id from the attachment id that I have?
This is the response from the get attachment method
{
  "attachmentId": string,
  "size": integer,
  "data": string
}

I need to get additional data of the attachments like content-type and file name etc. which can be obtained from the gmail.mesaage response of the connected mail, which can be obtained from the get message method, which needs message id

About the get attachment method of This is the response from the get attachment method, if you are saying about Method: users.messages.attachments.get, this method required to use messageId. How about this? If you are not talking about "Method: users.messages.attachments.get", I apologize.

You are correct. Initially I was passing the message id as well, but when I gave an empty string as messageID, it still worked, I’m not sure why the messageID is needed.

Unfortunately is not that straight forward (no that hard either ) you can follow the next steps to get that information and adapt them to your use case
1 use the message list method https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list
using the user email (it will require authentication to run succesfully)
This will give you a message ID (not the RFC2822 I assume you look for)
2 use the user id and the messageId from the previous response in the get method
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get
this will give you all the information thay you need from the message
I hioe you find this information useful

Yes I was aware of this scenario. But since I figured the attachment ID is globally unique there might be way to get the message id directly somehow from the attachment ID. Thanks anyway
